# Custom login with LDAP and Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to add Spring security to my project. I have custom login logic - advanced LDAP with custom encoding

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //TODO 
     }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        //TODO 
    }

    private boolean login(String login, String pass) {
        // custom login logic....

        return loginHandler.login(login, pass);
    }
}
```

Is there way, how to add login() method into configure method ?

Answer (score 0):

It's just Spring Security configuration class. It shouldn't have a login() method in it, it should store the configuration only.

Probably you would like to have something like this: https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/ - WebSecurityConfig should be good example.

Comment: I can't use that example, because I'm using different password encryption
 - org.jasypt.encryption.pbe#StandardPBEStringEncryptor

Comment: Have you tried it? Simply pass a different encoder and check for the result: .passwordEncoder(new StandardPBEStringEncryptor()).

Comment: Yes. I tried that. - java: incompatible types: org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor cannot be converted to org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder